# ESP32 - How to enable options in PlatformIO

Tags: esp32

For the ESP32 options are normally enabled with "make menuconfig".

PlatformIO with Atom also allows to create ESP32 projects with an empty source folder. It automatically installs an ESP-IDF 0.11.

I tried to create a new project following this [guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/Develop-ESP32-With-PlatformIO-IDE/).

I created the project, then inserted app_bt from this [source](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/bluetooth/ble_adv/main/app_bt.c), tried to compile - and it failed with "esp_bt.h" not found message.

After some reading it seems that it is created when "make menuconfig" is execute.

I also tried to copy one of the samples "sdkconfig.h" and put 
   `#define CONFIG_BT_ENABLED 1` in it. Same result as before.

Does anybody know how to create or enable this settings, so that compilation can be done successfully?

Comment: In `make menuconfig` did you enable Bluetooth?  ESP-IDF is updated very frequently - version 3.0 has been released so I'm also a bit concerned about the age of the development kit.

Comment: @stunbar that is the question. Where is something like male menuconfig in PlattformIO? It handles the tooolchain and build process. So I don't see where make can be called

Answer (score 3):

I followed the same tutorial and I also had this problem. It seems that esp_bt.h only appears in the latest release of esp-idf and some changes are not yet available in PlatformIO.

The sample espidf-ble-adv (available from the PlatformIO home) compiles correctly.

Now, how to use the latest espidf in PlatformIO is left as an exercise for the reader ;-) I'm still searching.